# Convert Image object to shape vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem with images in excel.

Now I import a image from a button and load it to an Image object.

And now the question. How can I convert that loaded image from Image object to a shape in a certain position ?
I found a temporary solution for this. Now I am saving the image URL temporally and when the save button is pressed a new shape from that URL is maked.

And the second question. How can I add a picture to the same Image object from that new generate shape ?